# What does the leading semicolon in a javascript file mean?

Tags: javascript

I have a file `jquery.flex.js` which starts with

[image]

What does beginning mean?

Comment: @Michael are you sure the OP *doesn't* mean 'comma'? Note to Dims: **`;`** is a semi-colon, **`,`** is a comma.

Comment: I am quite sure. But no-one is perfect ;-). Would be best if Dims confirmed.

Comment: Sorry I meant semicolon. Always mix them :shame:

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of this semicolon is to avoid an error if the file is concatenated with another one.

For example suppose you have two files like this :

```
(function(){
    ...
})()
```

It's OK as long as it's in two separate files but it's a error if you concatenate them as is frequently done to reduce the number of requests. What happens is that basically you have

```
(A)()(B)()
```

and that the engine is trying to call the result of `(A)()` with argument `B`.

Adding a semicolon to delimit the statements fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP knows the names for punctuation, but it does say 'comma' in the title :-/

Comment: @DavidThomas: I changed the title. The op most probably didn't know the proper name for the semicolon. But the later question "What does beginning mean?" says it all.

Comment: Yes, you did; but I'm not entirely convinced that the OP used the wrong word, and by changing the title you -potentially- completely changed the question. But you could well be right.

Comment: Huh, interesting use case. We concat all our javascript files and I've never run into this problem. I guess all our files have a trailing newline though. The file posted here has one at the top of the file as well, which should work just as well as a semicolon.

Comment: You rarely fall on this one but it happens, especially when you use a lot of IIFE. It happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since most modules start with a self-executing function `(function() {/* module code */}())` the trailing semicolon is just a security issue:

Take this example: if you load two js modules on your website, and the first one ends *without* a semicolon:

```
(function firstModule (window, undefined) {
    /* whatever this module does comes here */
})()
```

and the second one looks the same:

```
(function secondModule (window, undefined) {
    /* whatever this second module does comes here */
})()
```

Then you got a problem. Because your first module will execute itself and the second module will try to execute the result of the first modules self-execution:

```
(firstModule)()(secondModule)()
```

This would mostly break your code, or at least lead to unexpected behaviour.

So it is a simple pattern to add a leading semicolon to your module code:

```
;(firstModule)();(secondModule)()
```

And everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you're asking for, but your title says:

> What does comma mean in javascript?

It is used as a separator.

Comment: The title was changed; You might delete this answer.
You also have enough rep to update the title and flag for duplicates so…